# If condition fails to function properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script is sending messages to a given recipient in a column even if one was already sent. The goal is to search on the active sheet and check if two columns of the active row match the `if` condition. If so, then execute the `MailApp.sendEmail()` lines.

However, even if the row did not matches the condition, it sends another email.
I think this is due to either how I position my `for`-loop and the `if`, or there's something missing in my code.

Goal : If active row for two columns matches the condition > Send Email.
Anything else > Ignore / Skip row.

```
function sendOnEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dump");
  var startRow = 1;  // Bypass firts Row that contain Column Titles
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var rownum = startRow; rownum < data.length; rownum++) { //loop to search for reso == x && emailSent != y
    var casenum = data[rownum][5]; // Active Row for Case# Column 
    Logger.log("Captured Case#: " + casenum);
    var emailAddress = data[rownum][1];  // grabs the email address / Email Address Col
    Logger.log("Captured Email: " + emailAddress );

    var reso = data[rownum][12]; // check cell value / on Spreadsheet reso column is on Data Validation that's either "Yes" or empty.
    Logger.log("Captured Y/N: " + reso);
    var emailSent =data[rownum][17]; // Current active cell for col "DONE" 
    Logger.log("Captured DONE?: " + emailSent);
    var x = "Yes";
    var y = "DONE";

    if ( reso == x && emailSent != y ) {  // if this is true it should send email with details below if not it will do nothing.
      var body = "Hello!";
      body += '<p></p>';
      //Add to body ...

      var subject = "Message Subject" + casenum;

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, 
          {name: 'Automatic Teamline Email', htmlBody: body});
      sheet.getRange(rownum + 1, 19).setValue("DONE"); // This will set value of current cell to "DONE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm new at coding. Kindly suggest if I have to use other methods on calling data from the spreadsheet to efficiently use it with scripting. TIA.

Comment: Nice. I see you. Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: It seems like you are grabbing the DONE flag from column 17 and setting it in column 19. Is that on purpose? Even if it is like Rownum and it is a question of 0 based versus 1 based, I would expect them to be at most 1 apart.